# Efficiently plot database activity as a time series

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, performance, time-series

I am working on a system where 200,000+ records have been created in the past year and I need to plot their creation on a time series with various added filters. At this present, this requires performing lots of `count` queries (30 for each month plotted). How should these dates be stored for maximum speed?

One idea: store the most commonly-visualized data in a number of serialized fields containing `count`s for each day over the past month. Update each day with `cron` and serve up as necessary. (Where should these be stored - some new database table or a separate file accessible by Heroku cron?)

Comment: I like idea one.  But instead of a cron job,  if your database supports it,  update the day counts via a database trigger,  that way every thing is up to date all the time.

Comment: A question left unanswered.  where to store?  If you go with database triggers,  that pretty much implies you create a new table in the database with the day counts